# How to group observations in Mixed Effect models?

Tags: r, time-series, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, random-effects-model

I want to use mixed effect models for a fixed effect business closure policy (0 or 1) and daily newcases of covid19 and response is changes in jobs.

[image]

```
model1 = lmer(data=df,sales~ policy + consumption
    +(policy + consumption|State)+(policy + consumption|day))
```

The problem is that when policy is 1 (businesses are closed) I'm expecting that the policy coefficient always be negative ( 0 to 1 would result in decrease in jobs).

However, the policy gets positive for some states which is not acceptable. How can I avoid this?

```
   (Intercept)      policy lndailynewcases
AK -0.28983711 -0.48444661     0.001533898
AL -0.26865224 -0.33060127    -0.001486747
AZ -0.25708695 -0.04144235    -0.061188546
CA -0.18053142 -0.23598951    -0.058903321
CO -0.25308773 -0.38701125     0.007787721
CT -0.48690330 -0.03594221    -0.059452715
DC -0.47990935 -0.04962609    -0.071082720
DE -0.57804663 -0.30146321    -0.019703705
FL -0.14080790 -0.27519077    -0.047910993
GA -0.07360181 -0.24263749    -0.057068077
HI -0.33641693 -0.68802745     0.042243186
ID -0.33436577 -0.30298176     0.053145628
IL -0.27298908 -0.38410526    -0.026162309
IN -0.20217771 -0.26788326    -0.017143173
KS -0.59731841  **0.08072146**    -0.085423076
KY -0.15716580 -0.45975462     0.015061633
LA -0.33273304 -0.25543012    -0.024208915
MA -0.34399942 -0.18998038    -0.045279453
MD -0.36385070 -0.04050243    -0.044947863
ME -0.35047031 -0.07953991    -0.064349274
MI -0.38234266 -0.41682616    -0.016490988
MN -0.43944250 -0.31784459     0.001583994
MO -0.24693854 -0.27940508    -0.006332929
MS -0.30194673 -0.06194185    -0.106237656
MT  0.13190409 -0.27564693    -0.037935661
NC -0.46856422 -0.20685662    -0.012085286
ND -0.42158709  0.30205673    -0.158211823
NE -0.25238383  **0.01961256**    -0.021041915
NH -0.41341696 -0.13596592    -0.086275458
NJ -0.21923734 -0.30702041    -0.020355785
NM -0.40832325 -0.19700375    -0.066537246
NV -0.26318035 -0.34195408    -0.031242376
NY -0.30595014 -0.32089773    -0.030771649
OH -0.30973159 -0.37680999    -0.004253999
OK -0.06287309 -0.15600113     0.010278039
OR -0.27883207 -0.18317805    -0.055588308
PA -0.31374049 -0.32546013    -0.029973514
RI -0.37373881 -0.48780794     0.031529088
SC -0.32344006 -0.28635783    -0.032441752
SD  0.05928875 -0.07520328    -0.048188873
TN -0.23560453 -0.15381331    -0.039320767
TX -0.23812222 -0.32001636    -0.017213862
UT -0.23022141 -0.28634562    -0.007825178
VT -0.30831628 -0.56794421     0.053270975
WA -0.22294101 -0.30187306    -0.049401781
WI -0.71011415 -0.08304246    -0.005074675
WV -0.75504611 -0.07919280    -0.031922965
WY -0.25304558  **0.03531827**    -0.079320629
```

The mixed of the following formula is:

```
model1 = lmer(data=df,sales~ policy + consumption
    +(policy + consumption|State)+(policy + consumption|day))
```

[image: Random Effects]

Answer (score 4):

You could be misunderstanding how mixed effects models work. You say you want a seperate estimate for your fixed effects for each state. Well, that's exactly what you get when you fit random slopes for those fixed effects. There is an overall estimate for each fixed effect, and then an offset from the overall fixed effect for each state. You just neeed to extract the random slopes for each fixed effect and add them to overall fixed effect. Your last model, for which you say "I dont want my fixed effects to be random" actually gives you exactly what you want. Just bear in mind that in most software the random effects are assumed to be normally distributed.

If instead you fit seperate models for each state then you are losing a lot of statistical power in doing so. This is one of the reasons for choosing a model with random effects in the first place.

Comment: I've followed your advice but the effect of policy becomes positive. How to avoid that?

Comment: @AshLee you you completely changed the text in the question rendering my answer to the new question mostly irrelevant. Please roll back the change and add the new information to the original question otherwise it is impossible to help you.

Comment: Hi @RobertLong, can I have your opinion for this mixed effect model? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/570281/cross-mixed-model